# How do I uninstall apps that I can't find?

Tags: ios, applications

I want to uninstall AirBnb for example. However, in my 7 pages of apps and folders, I cannot find the app.

How do I remove AirBnb by name, or some sort of search method?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> General -> Stroage & iCloud Usage -> Under the storage section, not the icloud section, click on Manage Storage, and it will load for a while, and bring up all the apps and their corresponding sizes. It is not in alphabetical order, but from the biggest size to the smallest size. In those apps, search for the app you want, which in your case, is AirBnb. If you cannot find it in those, then you probably don't have it on your device in the first place.

After you find your app, click on it, and it will go into the info of that app. There will also be a Delete App option, just simply click on that, and Confirm by clicking on that "Delete App" option of the alert view that pops up.